# Python Web data colecting

Tags: python-3.x

I have 100 sets of BOL need to search on below web. However, i can't find the url to auto replace and keep searching.  anyone can help?

Tracking codes:
MSCUZH129687
MSCUJZ365758

The page I'm working on: 
https://www.msc.com/track-a-shipment

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.msc.com/track-a-shipment'

HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3346.9 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www.msc.com/track-a-shipment'
}

form_data = {'first': 'true',
             'pn': '1',
             'kd': 'python'}


def getJobs():
    res = requests.post(url=url, headers=HEADERS, data=form_data)
    result = res.json()
    jobs = result['Location']['Description']['responsiveTd']
    print(type(jobs))
    for job in jobs:
        print(job)

getJobs()
```

Answer (score 0):

tldr:  You'll likely need to use a headless browser like selenium to go to the page, input the code and click the search button.

The url to retrieve is generated by the javascript that runs when you click search.

The search button posts the link to their server so when it redirects you to the link the server knows what response to give you.

In order to auto generate the link you'd have to analyze the javascript and understand how it generates the code in order to generate the code yourself, post the code to their server and then make a subsequent get request to retrieve the results like the asp.net framework is doing.

Alternatively you can use a headless browser like selenium to go to the page, input the code and click the search button.  After the headless browser navigates to the results you can parse it from there.